# How to draw DrawString with an int variable

Tags: c++, gdi+

so I'm using Gdiplus and trying to output some text using the Drawstring method.

I have

```
graphics.DrawString(&myVariable, -1, &myFont, Gdiplus::PointF(x, y), &brushVariable);
```

However for the &myVariable parameter, I want to print out the integer from my for loop. Since it is an integer, I need to turn it into a string. I researched how to do this with stringstream and to_string(i), however the DrawString method still gives me an error saying that I haven't put in the right parameters. I know it is an issue with the &myVariable parameter, because I am unsure how I can convert an int to a string that I can dereference using &. 
The arguments are:
DrawString(std::string *, int, Gdiplus::font *, Gdiplus::PointF, Gdiplus::SolidBrush *);

Answer (score 1):

the following should work (include the `<sstream>` header):

```
//...
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    std::string printStr;
    {
        std::stringstream sstr;
        sstr << i;
        printStr = sstr.str();
    }
    //now, you can use printStr
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it still doesn't work. I still get a red squiggly line under the period of graphics.DrawString...

Comment: sorry, but that doesn't sound like something someone could solve without seeing more of your code.